# How to disable selection color/selecting cell in grid using windows forms

Tags: c#, windows, forms, grid, selection

I'm using C# Windows Forms.

I have a gridview. The user should not be able to select a cell. He can only (left-right) mouseclick a single cell at a time.

I did not find how to disable selecting. So I first set:

```
        this.grid.MultiSelect = false;
```

The user should not be able to select a cell, but it isn't bad if he is able to (as long as I did not set event handler for it). So my next though was: I should just disable selection color. So I made the selection color same as original:

```
        this.gridCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = this.gridCellStyle.BackColor;
        this.gridCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = this.gridCellStyle.ForeColor;
```

I fill my grid with random test values:

```
        grid.ColumnCount = 9;
        grid.Rows.Add(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
```

**Question:** Is there a better way to disable cell selection or it's default style?

Answer (score 1):

If you were going to do this, even though all you are doing is hiding from the user the indication that the cell is selected, you would set the selection colors to the normal colours which are definitely not transparent and definitely not the same unless you are going for an invisible ink solution (white on white).

The only bug here is your code.

As for your real problem

"The user should not be able to select a cell. He can only (left-right) mouseclick a single cell at a time".
Seeing as at least left clicking on a cell is one way of selecting it, we are all a bit stumped.

Comment: Hm, yes, when you click a cell, you select it. But I still have to implement a right mouseclick event (which handles a different method then left mouseclick). Since default right clicking does not select a cell, I figured that clicking in it's purest form does not necessarily mean selecting a cell.

Comment: The click is passed to the grid, that triggers the select routine, as would using the keyboard.

Comment: If the method that does cellselected is accessible you could override it.Seems like a loot of trouble to kill a standard aand expected behaviour though.